# Auto Notifications on events defined in Analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

I'm in process of evaluating an Analytic tool for our Android and Ios app. Firebase is one of the options being evaluated. have been researching around the possibility of defining events using Firebase Analytic and using the same to fire notifications to users. Would wish to know if that's possible and the approach towards implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics for Firebase has events distributed in 3 categories:

- [Automatically Collected Events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484) - Developer need not to write any code for these events to be collected.
- [Predefined Events](https://support.google.com/firebase/topic/6317484?hl=en) - A set of events that are provided by specific usecases, Eg. Retail/e-commerce.
- [Custom Events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#log_events) - Events that developer can log by writing code in the [logEvents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#logEvent(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) method call.

For sending notification based on events, the developer can create an [audience](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) in Analytics. This audience would contain the event for which the developer needs to send the notification. Finally, Go to Notifications in Firebase console and select Target as User Segment, App as the app AND audience that was created in Analytics created with the event. Sending notification would send it to all the app users who are contained in the audience definition that logged the event of your choice.

Comment: Thank u AniV. I want to precisely know if this can be automatically triggered like some analytic tools do for ex: Localytics. When ever my user exits out of cart page without making a payment, I want to reach out to him and provide assistance if required.

Comment: For that you can make use of the Firebase Cloud Functions and make use of the Analytics Trigger as mentioned in this doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events and here is a sample code for similar kind of use case https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/coupon-on-purchase

Comment: Is there a way to disable some automatic events? I mean not all the automatically collected events, just some of them that I don't need.